# SQL syntax formatting on Android Studio or IntelliJ?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I'm surprised that these IDEs don't have one but PyCharm has it.

Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IntelliJ support SQL but only the ultimate edition and since the android studio is built on community edition so consequently, it doesn't support SQL.

I looked it up and PyCharm Community Edition does not support database / SQL only  the ultimate edition

take a look at this [comparison](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html) and [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html)